# primary key autoincrement not working on android database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
  public static final String Database_Name="content.db";
public static final int Database_Version=1;
public static final String Table_Name="images";
public static final String Column1="contentid";
public static final String Column2="content_type";
public static final String Column3="content";
public static final String Column4="has_update";
public static final String Column5="server";
public static final String Column6="_id";
public static final String Create_Database = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name +
                " (" + Column6 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                Column1 + " LONG, " + 
                Column2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                Column3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                Column4 + " INTEGER, " + 
                Column5 + " INTEGER); ";
```

i am creating a table in android database by using above code and executing Create_Database query but i am getting an error in logcat saying autoincrement can be assigned to only an integer primary key?
what am i doing wrong here?

```
02-17 21:08:27.016: E/SQLiteLog(8460): (1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

this is the error i am getting in logcat.Any help.....

Comment: can you give me the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 public static final String Create_Database = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name +
            " (" + Column6 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            Column1 + " LONG, " + 
            Column2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            Column3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            Column4 + " INTEGER, " + 
            Column5 + " INTEGER " + ")";
```

A column declared **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** will [autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).

Comment: What is the difference between your code and question. I can't see differences clearly. Can you indicate?

Comment: hey can you solve one more query for me after doing this i am getting error in logcat file as code1 column content not found in table why is that column not created in the table am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try `NOT NULL` to prevent second error.

Also try like this `INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Answer (score -1):

try this

INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NULL

it works for me